# How to merge files in Linux while deleting the source files

Tags: linux, files, cat

I have 2 large files (of about 27 GB each), which I need to merge. They were originally one whole ZIP file, but I split it. The problem with the cat command is that it creates a new file which has the source files' content, which I do not want to do (since I don't have that much disk space left).

Is there an alternative to cat that supports merging files while simultaneously deleting the source files?

Comment: How did you split it? Would just concatenating the two files yield a valid Zip archive?

Comment: @Kusalananda I think so. I used the split command, by following this guide: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-split-a-large-tar-file-into-multiple-small-files-using-split-command-in-linux/

Comment: Do you have space under `/tmp` or elsewhere (`/var`?) that you could use temporarily?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes I do have a /tmp directory, and I also have an 8 GB flash drive

Comment: How much free space in `/tmp`? (`df -h /tmp`)

Comment: @Kusalananda I don't have a separate /tmp partition, just a /tmp directory. I have 28.3 GB left.

Comment: And in the current directory where the archive bits live? (`df -h .`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89690/discussion-between-avery-alejandro-and-kusalananda).

Comment: @Kusalananda It worked.

Comment: I'm kinda relieved to hear that :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Summary of [discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89690/discussion-between-avery-alejandro-and-kusalananda))

You have 28.3 GB left in the partition that holds your current directory, and the second part of the archive is 27.8 GB.  This means that you should be able to append the second part of the archive onto the first part of the archive.

Assuming the two parts are called `part1` and `part2`:

```
cat part2 >>part1
```

After this, `part1` would be the complete archive file (and `part2` could be deleted).

The only issue is that there usually is a reserved buffer of space on a Unix filesystem that ordinary users can't fill (it's usually a few percent of the total partition size).  Since the size restrictions here are so tight, I'm not entirely sure you would be within these size limits.

The remedy for that is either to run as the root user (who's not restricted in filling up the reserved space), or to simply clear out some large unneeded files.

To run as root, either bring up a root shell with `sudo -s` and run the `cat` as above, or do

```
sudo tee -a part1 <part2 >/dev/null
```

Comment: Okay, now time to figure out how to extract this ZIP file with the little disk space I have left...

Comment: @AveryAlejandro It would be difficult. If the contents is compressed, then it would be *very* difficult. That's all I can say.

Comment: They're not compressed. It's just stored

Comment: @AveryAlejandro You would have to find another 60 GB of space, and extract thing to there, or copy the archive there and extract _from_ there.

Comment: Deleted Android Studio, and all my virtual machines... FML

Comment: @AveryAlejandro Sacrifices were made...